# Browser hisory not stored url while using php redirect

Tags: php, redirect, browser-history

This problem occurs in all browsers except firefox.

In my website, for ex, the home page will be like this `www.example.com`

After click signin link, it will be `www.example.com/signin.php`

After finsihed authentication, I will redirect the page using header function in php to user's prfoile. So after logged in my page wil be like this. www.example.com

If the user clicked back button, I will check the session in signin.php and again redirect to user's profile page.

It works fine for me in firefox. Other than that all browsers, If I used header redirection, it will not store the page in browser's history.

I mean, I am redirecting the user after authentication in signin page. So the signin.php url not stored in browser history.

So If I use back button, it will go to previous site what I opened before opening my site.

Can anyone help?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: pleas post the parts of your code which belong to this problem. welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score -1):

use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for redirection where user came from